# Triple boot OSX, Win7, Linux - broke my Win 7 install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, uefi, macosx

Note, this is not really an Ubuntu question but I expect there are lots of smart Linux gurus here that may know the answer - so please excuse my posting here:

I'm desperately needing help: I've had a functional dual boot OSX (Maveriks) and Win 7 setup for a while and when I created my disk partitions I allowed room for a Linux partition.

Today I installed Fedora 20 into the remaining space but now I can no longer boot into windows 7, I get the message "No bootable device "insert boot disk and press any key".

I'm using rEFInd for my boot manager. I can  boot OSX and Fedora, but not win7.

Any ideas on how to repair my win7 install to boot again?

Note, I'm **not** trying to have win 7 boot via GRUB, this is an EFI machine (iMac) and I want to boot directly from rEFInd - as such finding a solution doesn't seem as simple as doing some google searching. (I've searched a lot and found nothing).

Comment: I am sorry but I still flagged you question as off topic, since well... it is. since Grub is the default in Ubuntu and you don't want to use Grub I think this question is so far of from a Ubuntu use case I think you could better ask this question in an other place, for example in the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No probs Wouter, I've solved my issue and this is just as relevant to Ubuntu users (Fedora also uses Grub, I just didn't want to use Grub to chain through to windows when rEFInd can boot it directly)

I've answered my own question as it may help Ubuntu users equally .

Comment: Note: for questions considered offtopic, stackexchange should consider the ability to move the questions to the correct site - it must be in their best interest - I couldn't even find that Unix & Linux stack exchange site by searching - your link is the first time I've seen it (and I'm a user of Linux for > 15 years)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! @larku: If your answer worked for you then please consider marking it as the accepted answer so others may more easily find it in the future. There is no need to add "SOLVED" to the title. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out. See the [help center](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @larku Migrating questions from site to site is an ability of Stack Exchange, it's just not often used on Ask Ubuntu. But maybe this should be considered for migration to [Super User](http://superuser.com). Migration happens only *after* a question is closed / on hold.

Comment: @EliahKagan actually we migrate questions even before that. Sometimes immediately we get green light in the target site.

Comment: @Braiam They're not closed by the moderator doing the migration?

Comment: @EliahKagan IMO no. The moderator just migrate the stuff and here community lock the post and remove it after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I finally figured this out - this is probably just as relevant for Ubuntu users as it is for any Linux distro so I'll give my solution here should anyone else have the same issue.

The fix was simple.

1. boot into OSX
2. modify `/EFI/refind/refind.conf` to enable gptsync (`showtools gptsync`)
3. reboot back to the refind boot menu
4. choose "Start Hybrid MBR tool" and allow it to alter the MBR to what it detects
5. rejoice that your windows partition now boots once again.

At step (2) you need to uncomment the modify the 'showtools' line (uncomment or add as needed) to list:

```
showtools gptsync
```

Now, I just need to work out how to have 1 entry for my Fedora boot item instead of the 5 that rEFInd finds and shows.